# Python : How do you convert variable into list?

Tags: python

I have a variable which I need to convert into list so I can call them using b[0]

```
a = http://yahoo.com, http://google.com, http://bing.com

b = 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com', 'http://bing.com'
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a variable

Comment: Your syntax for `a` isn't valid, but otherwise `b = a.split(',')`

Comment: how do I convert from a into b ?

Comment: `a` is a syntax error. You can convert it to `b` by adding some quotes.

Comment: thanks @CoryKramer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line `b = 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com', 'http://bing.com'` already declares `b` as a tuple (which supports `b[0]`)

See:

```
b = 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com', 'http://bing.com'

b[0]
Out[690]: 'http://yahoo.com'
```

If you want it to be a list instead, use one of the following:

1. `b = list('http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com', 'http://bing.com')`
2. `b = ['http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com', 'http://bing.com']`

---

Converting from `a` to `b` can be done with `b = [str(item) for item in a]` which creates a list with the objects inside the list `a` and converts them into strings.

*Note that this is not possible unless `'http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com', 'http://bing.com` are already variables which can't happen since `http://yahoo.com` isn't a valid variable name, as shown here:*

```
    http://yahoo.com = 1
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

A working example will be:

```
a = 1,2,3
b = [str(item) for item in a]
print(a)
print(b)
print(type(b))


(1, 2, 3)
['1', '2', '3']
<class 'list'>
```